# How to Detect and Handle Collisions Between a Ball and Curved Paddle in JavaScript Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, simulation

I'm working on a JavaScript canvas project to simulate a pinball game. I've reached the point where I need to implement collision detection between the ball (a circle) and the flippers (curved paddles). Initially, I set the flippers as rectangles for simplicity, but as I've progressed with styling the board, I've given the flippers a more realistic curved shape.

The problem I'm facing is that my current collision detection logic, which works well for rectangular objects, does not work for these curved flippers. Given that the flippers have a specific arc and are not simple rectangles, I'm unsure how to approach collision detection and handling.

I attempted to modify my existing collision detection function to account for the curves, but without success. My expectation is for the ball to bounce off the flipper realistically, considering the flipper's curvature and the ball's trajectory.

Here is a simplified representation of my flipper and ball classes, and the checkers that i was using to check the ball's colission with the flippers, but of course, does not work anymore, because the flippers are no longer rectangles:

[How the paddles/flippers are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVY3d.png)

In the simplified version of the code below, only the left flipper is shown. I think this is sufficient for me to understand the logic required for this simulation.

```
// Accessing the canvas and context
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Global variables for easier access
const W = canvas.width;
const H = canvas.height;
const GRAVITY = 0.05;

let pause = false;
let leftKeyIsPressed = false;
let ballsArray = []; // Array to store all the balls

// Class defining a flipper
class Flipper {
  constructor(x, y, length, width, angularSpeed, maxAngle, side) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
    this.angularSpeed = angularSpeed;
    this.angle = 30;
    this.maxAngle = maxAngle; // Maximum rotation angle
    this.side = side;
    
  }
  // Method to update flipper's angle
  update() {
    if (this.side === 'left' && leftKeyIsPressed) {
      this.angle = Math.max(this.angle - this.angularSpeed, -this.maxAngle);
      console.log('Left Flipper Angle: ' + this.angle);
    } else if (this.side === 'left') {
      this.angle = Math.min(this.angle + this.angularSpeed, 30);
    }
  }
  // Method to draw flipper on canvas
  draw() {
    ctx.save(); // Save the current context state
    ctx.translate(this.x, this.y); // Set the origin to the flipper's pivot point
    ctx.rotate(this.angle * Math.PI / 180); // Convert angle to radians and rotate
    // Draw the main body of the flipper
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(0, 0, this.width / 2, Math.PI * 1.5, Math.PI * 0.5, true);
      ctx.arc(this.length, 0, this.width / 3, Math.PI * 0.5, Math.PI * 1.5, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    // Style and fill the flipper body
    ctx.fillStyle =  'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    // Draw the pivot circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, this.width / 5, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.restore(); // Restore the context to its original state
  }
}
// Instantiating the flippers with a maximum angle they can rotate
const leftFlipper = new Flipper(canvas.width * 0.35, canvas.height - 90, 60, 30, 5, 30, 'left');
// Class defining a ball
class Ball {
  constructor(x, y, radius, speedX, speedY, material) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
    this.speedX = speedX;
    this.speedY = speedY;
    this.material = material;
    this.onThrowingMechanism = false;
    this.setPhysicalProperties(material);
  }
  setPhysicalProperties(material) {
    switch (material) {
      case 'steel':
        this.mass = 1;
        this.restitution = 0.15;
        break;
      case 'wood':
        this.mass = 0.5;
        this.restitution = 0.3;
        break;
      case 'rubber':
        this.mass = 0.25;
        this.restitution = 0.8;
        break;
      default:
        this.mass = 1;
        this.restitution = 0.4;
    }
  }
  // Method to draw the ball on the canvas
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#00ff00"; // Green color for the ball
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}
// Function to create a new ball and add it to the balls array
function createBall() {
  const speedX = 0; // Random horizontal speed
  const speedY = 5; // Always start with the same upward speed
  const newBall = new Ball(200, 100, 10, speedX, speedY, 'steel');
  ballsArray.push(newBall);
}
// Function to remove a ball from the array and create a new one
function removeBall(index) {
  ballsArray.splice(index, 1);
  createBall();
}
// Function to handle all ball collisions
function handleCollisions() {
  ballsArray.forEach((ball, index) => {
    if (!pause) {
    // Update the position if the ball is not on the mechanism
    if (!ball.onThrowingMechanism) {
      ball.x += ball.speedX;
      ball.y += ball.speedY;
    }
    // Bottom border collision
    if (ball.y + ball.radius > H && ball.speedY > 0) {
      // alert('You lost! Click OK to launch a new ball.');
      removeBall(index);
      return;
    }
    // Left flipper collision - THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP WITH
    if (ball.x > leftFlipper.x - leftFlipper.width / 2 - ball.radius &&
      ball.x < leftFlipper.x + leftFlipper.width / 2 + ball.radius &&
      ball.y > leftFlipper.y - leftFlipper.height / 2 - ball.radius &&
      ball.y < leftFlipper.y + leftFlipper.height / 2 + ball.radius) {
      ball.speedY *= -1; // Reflect the ball vertically
    }
  }
  });
}
// The update function, called once per frame
function update() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'palegreen';
  ctx.fillRect(26, 20, W, H);
  // Update and draw each ball
  ballsArray.forEach(ball => {
    if (!ball.onThrowingMechanism) {
        // Normal motion if the ball is not on the arc path
        ball.x += ball.speedX;
        ball.y += ball.speedY;      
    } 
    ball.draw();
  });
  handleCollisions();
  // Draw flippers after the balls
  leftFlipper.draw();
  leftFlipper.update();
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

// Event listeners for key presses
window.onload = () => {
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftKeyIsPressed = true;
    } 
  });
  document.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
    if (event.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      leftKeyIsPressed = false;
    } 
  });
  createBall();  // Start the game with one ball
  update();
};
```